# Easiest way to get an NSDate representation of "the next 7am that will occur" in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I figure I can achieve what I want by using `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`, but that would run something like the following:

- Get "now"
- Create an `NSDateComponents` from "now".
- If "now" is pre-7am, then use today's date.
- If "now" is post-7am, use tomorrow's date.

  - If today is the last day of the month, increase month, set day to 1.

    - If it was December, increase year by 1 also.
- Set hour, minute, second.
- Create a new `NSDate`.

It all seems very long-winded, but that appears to be what other answers on here suggest, and the documentation doesn't offer any clues. I'm going back and forth between all the date and calendar classes I can find.

Is there a simple way to ask for the "next occurring 7am"?

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tried it, but I think this would work:

- Get Now date.
- Create `NSDateComponents` from Now.
- Set hour component to 7.
- Convert 7am date components back to an `NSDate`.
- If the 7am date is later than Now, you're done.
- Otherwise, use `-[NSCalendar dateByAddingComponents:options:]` to advance the 7am date by one day.

I'm not sure if that last step would do the right thing if a daylight savings change happened between one 7am and the next.