# Change label every day at the same time

Tags: ios, swift

I'm programming a basic quote app where I want to add a "daily quote". I have a NSObject with the quotes/authors and also a function which randomises the quotes.

```
        let range: UInt32 = UInt32(quotes.count) //my array is called quotes
        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))
        let quote = quotes[randomNumber]
        let quoteString = quote.quote
        let authorString = quote.person

        self.quoteLabel.text = quoteString
        self.personLabel.text = authorString
```

How do I create a function in which the quote is only changed every day (at midnight/00:00?)

I have been trying to use NSDate and NSTimer, but understand that these will be cancelled when the app is closed. I have also been trying to implement this code [Update Every Day in swift syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666734/update-every-day-in-swift-syntax) - but without any results.

**How do I change the quote every day at midnight and keep it there throughout the day?**

I'm new to programming and would really appreciate a detailed answer with code, I have only been coding for a couple of months just - thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if day change has occurred](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016119/determine-if-day-change-has-occurred)

Comment: remember the last open / refresh / load date, when your app is opened determine if a new quote should be loaded via simply date arithmetics. Then start a timer or schedule a local notification to run the quote requery.

Comment: Why not try for local notification for this?  Schedule 64 notification for next 64days for mid night then when get 64th notification then again update for next 64 date.

Comment: @VibhaSingh That's a possible solution, but complete overkill.

Comment: Looks pretty similar to this question that was asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38106791/how-do-i-run-a-code-every-day-at-a-set-time-swift/38107648

Comment: That sounds perfect, could you please show me how? @luk2302

Comment: Thank you for the idea @VibhaSingh but I must say that sounds a bit ineffective.

Comment: @CaseyFleser I tried the code from your linked question - no results once again. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe? sorry that it is objc)

```
- (void)checkDateAndSwitchLabel
{
    //get previous Cached data when label refreshed
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger cachedDay = [defaults integerForKey:@"appDate"];
    NSInteger cachedHour = [defaults integerForKey:@"appDateHour"];

    //get current data
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSInteger currentDay = [components day];
    NSInteger currentHour = [components hour];

    //compare
    if (cachedDay - currentDay >= 1 || cachedHour > currentHour) {
        //change Label
    }

    //save new values
    [defaults setInteger:currentDay forKey:@"appDateDay"];
    [defaults setInteger:currentHour forKey:@"appDateHour"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Tried to add my randomisation to your //change Label --> nope it doesn't work. No quote/author is shown in the labels during run in the simulator :( thank you for your help, I'm sure we can figure something out.

Comment: I translated your code to swift and put it my viewDidLoad function - no results @NikKov

Comment: This is an example how to do it, i didn't try this code but the concept can be like this

Comment: Could you please help me find the correct code? I don't know how do get it functioning? Thank you for your time.  @Nik Kov