# How would you go about implementing a "dayDidChange" method, while avoiding the use of NSTimer?

Tags: objective-c, ios

How would you go about implementing a "**dayDidChange**" method?

I have a **dateLabel**, that needs updating, when the **day changes**.

I already had 2 solutions implemented. But gave up on them.

1st, on viewWillAppear, I would set my label. Chances for date changing when the user is viewing the VC are VERY small ... and it wouldn't really introduce any "errors" to execution But still, it's not perfect.

2nd, I also implemented an NSTimer with intervals of 1 second. Works great. But I'm not too found of the idea of having a method being called if there is a chance that I don't need to do it.

Are there any other options? I need to update that label, when the day changes. Also, is it possible to use NSNotificationCenter with this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938807/can-i-get-a-notification-when-a-new-day-begins

Comment: While that does solve my problem, I am looking to avoid NSTimer. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the time left on the day and set a timer to it. You can also listen to UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification. Note that this notification will be fired not only when the date changes, but for timezone adjustments and other changes. Keep in mind also that the firing of the notification will be triggered only if your app is not in an inactive state.

Answer (score 6):

In your appliciation delegate, implement the following method: -`(void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application`

This method is called when the day changes, or if the device's time has been changed in the background for whatever reason (such as changes to time zone).

hope it helps. happy coding :)

Comment: Lovely! This solves my problem in a very elegant fashion. Thank you very much Sir

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do so, and I can elaborate more on them if needed.
But here is a nice quick trick

use this code in your app delegate
it will listen to time changes (when the date or time changes dramatically) and when that happens - run a test and update the label if needed.

read me about this here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html

It's just a quick simple way of doing it without timers.

```
- (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"Time has changed, do a test and update the label if needed");
    // [yourViewController runTimeTestAndUpdateFunction];
}
```