# Checking for a Day Change - Timezone Adjusted

Tags: swift, timezone, nsdate, nsnotificationcenter

I just took a stab at creating some code (pasted below) that would check for a day change. However, now [I'm reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938807/can-i-get-a-notification-when-a-new-day-begins) that there's a special function for day changes.

**NSCalendarDayChangedNotification**

Apparently it works in iOS8 and later. But people keep using the phrase "you can listen to it"... as if using that function is like tuning into a radio station. I looked it up and the last WWDC provided a presentation with some relevant code:

> Reacting to the Change of Day • You may want to run some code when the
>   day changes NSCalendarDayChangedNotification • Example

```
noteCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
observer = [noteCenter addObserverForName:NSCalendarDayChangedNotification
object:nil
queue:nil
usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
// your code here
}];
```

**My Question**

The PDF I found doesn't say much else though. So my question is how does this function work? The PDF makes it seem like it truly is just this simple, paste that code in and I'm done. Is that true? Will it adjust for timezones? Do I have to enable this notification center that it is referencing?

**My code (not sure if it would work):**

```
    //Find out if it's a new day
    let lastDateUsed_NSDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let endOf_LastDateUsed = lastDateUsed_NSDefault.objectForKey("lastDateUsed") as! NSDate! {
        print("Success! NSUserDefault key: 'lastDateUsed' returned \(endOf_LastDateUsed)")
        //Check if the day has changed

        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let startOfToday = calendar.startOfDayForDate(now)

        if endOf_LastDateUsed.compare(startOfToday) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending {
            //endOf_LastDateUsed is greater than startOfToday.
            print("Do nothing! Last date used must have been today!")
        } else if endOf_LastDateUsed.compare(startOfToday) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending {
            //Day has changed. Run alert.


            //Save "endOfToday" date value to NSDefault
            let endOfToday = startOfToday.dateByAddingTimeInterval(24 * 60 * 60)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(endOfToday, forKey:"lastDateUsed")
            print("Time stored in NSDefault: \(endOfToday)")
        }

    }
    else {
        print("Failure! NSUserDefault key: 'lasteDateUsed' returned nothing. No record.")
        //First time user - Set end of today
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let startOfToday = calendar.startOfDayForDate(now)
        print("startOfToday: \(startOfToday)")
        let endOfToday = startOfToday.dateByAddingTimeInterval(24 * 60 * 60)
        //Store
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(endOfToday, forKey:"lastDateUsed")

        print("Time stored in NSDefault: \(endOfToday)")
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSCalendarDayChangedNotification)  (which was slightly harder to locate than I'd have hoped, admittedly) is reasonably clear:

> Posted whenever the calendar day of the system changes, as determined by the system calendar, locale, and time zone.

So yes, it should handle daylight saving changes appropriately, given that it knows about the time zone. I don't know about enabling the notification centre, but that should be easy enough to test by adjusting the system clock or time zone on a device and seeing what happens.

(What *isn't* clear from the docs is whether this event is fired if the date is changed via manual intervention, e.g. through changing the system time or time zone in a way that directly changes the date. It would be worth you experimenting with that.)

Comment: Thanks Jon. I tried implementing it and got compiler errors saying commas are missing so I guess Apple didn't supply read to use code! As I read the documentation I also started to question whether this new iOS8 code would accomplish what I desire: " code that would check for a day change". The documentation says "If the the device is asleep when the day changes, this notification will be posted on wakeup. Only one notification will be posted...". Will running this in my viewDidLoad return whether or not the day has changed since my app's last use? There's very little to read online about this

Comment: @DaveG: Running what? The code you posted, or the event subscription? I note that in your code you're assuming all days are 24 hours long... that's a dangerous assumption in the face of daylight saving time.

Comment: The event subscription. I see how daylight savings could really mess things up. I guess ultimately my main concern is using the best methodology to detect a day change since my app was last used. I thought if iOS8 had added something, that I should use it but if you can suggest a sort of best-practice that experienced developers use, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @DaveG: I don't think the event subscription is really for that sort of requirement - I think it's more for apps which need to update something while they're running. Not being an iOS developer, I wouldn't know details of best practice here - but you should think carefully about what you want to happen if the user has manually changed the time zone or adjusted the system clock. I wouldn't expect you to need to work out the end of the day as well as the start though.